# python.exe: No module named django-admin Vscode Error

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

```
    (venv) PS D:\Project> python -m django-admin startproject home .
    D:\Project\venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named django-admin
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong. I am pretty new to this.
Vscode doesn't show python in the status bar. I have already set the interpreter.
Every video on Youtube shows how to create the project directly.
Google gave me no results on this question.

Comment: delete "python -m"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its just `django-admin startproject home .` without the `python -m`

[here's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/)